# HTML:Server Tag Not well Formed

Tags: asp.net, html

Hi all I get the **Server Tag Not Well Formed** error on the following line of code.

```
<a class="button"><span><input id="btnEmbedCodes" type="button" 
value="Click for Embed Codes" onclick='javascript:window.open("%=ExternalLink%>","ExternalFeeds","height=575,width=675,
scrollbars=yes,overflow-x:hidden")'; Style="width:165px" /></span></a>
```

Please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> window.open("%=ExternalLink%>"
> ```

In this starting "<" is missing. Seems like that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you missed a < in the first argument of your javascript function

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the opening bracket before ExternalLink

Answer (score 0):

You have missed less than sign (<) before ExternalLink and also surround it with single quotes rather than double quotes.

Thanks.